# Removing Verbose Form Handling

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to django but realize that this type of form handling is very verbose. Is there any way to shorten statements such as this? I looked into ModelForms but I'm not sure its applicable here (maybe I'm wrong?).

```
    if 'solve_comment' in request.POST:
        ticket.state_id = 5
        text = request.POST['solve_comment']
        comment.text = text + " (descended back to Level 1)"
        ticket.group_id = 6
        comment.comment_type = "solving_note"
        comment.content_type = ContentType.objects.get(id=114)
        comment.object_id = ticket.id
        comment.created_by_id = request.user.id
        comment.save()
        ticket.save()
    if 'closing_note' in request.POST:
        ticket.state_id = 6
        text = request.POST['closing_note']
        ticket_issue = request.POST['ticket_issue']
        comment.text = text + (" (%s)" %ticket_issue)
        comment.comment_type = "closing_note"
        comment.content_type = ContentType.objects.get(id=114)
        comment.object_id = ticket.id
        comment.created_by_id = request.user.id
        comment.save()
        ticket.save()
    if 'private_note' in request.POST:
        text = request.POST['private_note']
        comment.text = text
        comment.comment_type = "private_note"
        #this line needs to be fixed
        comment.content_type = ContentType.objects.get(id=114)
        comment.object_id = ticket.id
        comment.created_by_id = request.user.id
        comment.save()
    if 'reopen-ticket-button' in request.POST:
        ticket.state_id = 2
        ticket.save()
    if 'hold-ticket-button' in request.POST:
        ticket.state_id = 4
        ticket.save()
    if 'take_ownership' in request.POST:
        ticket.assignee_id = request.user.id
        if ticket.state_id == 1:
            ticket.state_id = 2
        ticket.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle forms with Django [Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/), you have an [API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form)